# Primary key composed with one foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping

I am doing a JEE web application with Hibernate.
I'm doing the mapping in beans with annotations.

I show the

[image]
Despite my research on the forum and other web site, I can not make my primary key compose with a foreign key as on the image above.

I just managed to put my "id-command" key in FK but I would like her to compose the PK.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Have a good day.

Comment: You show us the database schema (btw, text is preferable to links or images because they can break) but you didn't show us your mapping. How are we supposed to help you spot errors?

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your answer.

When the application is first launched, the database does not have a table. They are created by Hibernate.

I give you my code (I do not have the getters and setters in the code that I give you) :
Class **BonLivraison** (The end of code of this class is juste a try)

package sii.dsi.beans;

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table
public class BonLivraison implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id_bon_livraison;
    @Column(nullable=false, length=255, unique=false)
    private String numero_bon_livraison;
    @Column(nullable=false, unique=false)
    private double montant_bon_livraison;
    @Column(nullable=false, unique=false)
    private Date date_bon_livraison;
    @Column(nullable=false, unique=false)
    private Date date_depot_facture;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_commande")
    private PosteLigne poste_ligne_id_commande; 
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_posteligne")
    private PosteLigne poste_ligne_id;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

Class **Commande** :

```
package sii.dsi.beans;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.*;

import sii.dsi.beans.Affaire;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table
public class Commande implements Serializable{
    @Column
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id_commande;
    @Column(nullable=false, length=255, unique=false)
    private String numero_commande;
    @Column(nullable=false, length=255, unique=false)
    private String numero_bc;
    @OneToOne
    private Affaire affaire;

}
```

Class **PosteLigne** :

```
package sii.dsi.beans;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table
public class PosteLigne implements Serializable{

    @EmbeddedId
    private PosteLignePK poste_ligne_pk;
    @Id
    private int id_poste_ligne;
    @Column(nullable=false, unique=false)
    private double montant_poste_ligne;
    @Column(nullable=false, unique=false)
    private boolean clos;
    @Column(nullable=false, unique=false)
    private int numero_ligne;

}
```

Class **PosteLignePK** :

```
package sii.dsi.beans;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Embeddable
public class PosteLignePK implements Serializable{

    private int id_poste_ligne;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_commande")
    private Commande commande;


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + id_poste_ligne;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        PosteLignePK other = (PosteLignePK) obj;
        if (id_poste_ligne != other.id_poste_ligne)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Error message :

> A Foreign key refering sii.dsi.beans.PosteLigne from
>   sii.dsi.beans.BonLivraison has the wrong number of column. should be 2

I think the problem is at the end of the class BonLivraison.

Thank for your help

Comment: Hi! On StackOverflow, answers are meant to be answers, not replies. Edit your question rather than posting an answer.